# JQuery Dropdown Menu <li> Links Do Not Work In Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently implemented a jQuery dropdown from this developer's site: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/, and it looks and works fine on my site in Chrome and Firefox (my site is: http://www.ExpeditionerSafaris.com).

However, in Internet Explorer (of course), the li links do not work.

Here is the code:

```
function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.initEvents();
}

DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents: function () {
        var obj = this;

        obj.dd.on('click', function (event) {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    }
}

$(function () {

    var dd = new DropDown($('#dd'));

    $(document).click(function () {
        // all dropdowns
        $('.wrapper-dropdown-5').removeClass('active');
    });

});
```

Comment: could you open your IE debugger tool and see what error it throws

Comment: I don't see any difference between Chrome and IE 9. "Doesn't work" leaves quite a bit open to interpretation. Maybe it could be more specific?

Comment: @kato The links do not work. I click but nothing happens in IE. In Chrome, I can click through to the links.

Comment: So it sounds like the problem doesn't actually have much to do with the dropdown menu then. Since the only dropdown on the page is the big dropdown in the page (not the nav), I assumed you meant that. You do need to define the question a bit if you want some serious answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem of `jquery confliction` refer http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

The code has problems

```
$(function () {//here is problem of `$` conflictions

    var dd = new DropDown($('#dd'));

    $(document).click(function () {
        // all dropdowns
        $('.wrapper-dropdown-5').removeClass('active');
    });

});
```

I checked it and code has error

```
Error: TypeError: $ is not a function
Source File: http://www.expeditionersafaris.com/
Line: 426
```

Use `jQuery(function ()` in place of `$(function ()` and then try, or use `jQuery.noConflict()` function

Comment: @Rohan_Kumar, I've gotten rid of the 426 error but still having trouble with the links, even after I tried the above.

Comment: @TheExpeditioner as I checked the url http://www.expeditionersafaris.com/ is working in `IE 9`, also the confliction error removed from page ,checked in `Firefoz error console`.

Comment: Change the line `obj.dd.on('click', function (event) {` to `obj.dd.on('click','ul.dropdown li', function (event) {` and then check.

Answer (score 0):

In your `initEvents` method. Do not pass `event` as it collides with IE event, So make it

```
obj.dd.on('click', function (evt) {
    //evt is jQuery normalized event object

    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: That seems like a likely cause for an IE bug.

Comment: I have fixed the bug, but the links in the dropdown still do not work.